# Wordpress plugin for dependent drop down lists

Tags: wordpress

Well, I know i'm going to be downvoted, but i think it's worth the shot.

I never worked with wordpress, and find it very displeasing to work with. A friend of mine asked me to implement a feature and i just don't have the time to understand it's inner works.

What i'm looking for is a plugin that let me have some sort of a tree, representing localization, kind of like:

```
Country
   State
      City
         Person 1
         Person 2
         Person 3
```

and let me represent it with dependent select boxes that will list the people that belong to in the city, in the state, in the country i select?

Thanks for your help, and i'm sorry if this falls out the scope of SO

P.S.: yes, i have looked and looked in the [wordpress plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) and haven't found anything.

Comment: Same problem here. Searching for a similar plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you will never find a plugin with such a feature.

This is a simple rule-based interface in a structure database.

I suggest you create a database structure parallel to wordpress with the characteristics necessary for the hierarchy shown in your example.

After this model database, you can use the the class wpdb() in wordpress to access this table and perform the query. In the link below there are instructions for this:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

If you want to use the structure of the actual wordpress users, there are some plugins for listing users:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-user-listing/
http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-list/

But user registration provided by wordpress can not provide detailed information about the user that you need.

Hope this helps.